# Shims for library class not created

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I want to use fakes(shims) to mock nj4x library. I followed the guidelines here to generate them:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174.aspx](http://MS%20fakes)

However fakes for some classes are not generated.
I tried solutions suggested here: [Shims are not generated for .NET methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154182/shims-are-not-generated-for-net-methods)

[Shims are not generated for .NET methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154182/shims-are-not-generated-for-net-methods)

but still not working.
When I build, I get this warning:

> Cannot generate shim for nj4x.Strategy: Could not resolve assembly
>   'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?.

My assembly file for now is

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/"
       Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="nj4x" Version="2.5.6.0"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add Namespace="nj4x!"/>
    <Add Namespace="nj4x.metatrader!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

I have tried several other thins too but not working.
I am really stuck here.

Comment: Without downloading and trying it, my guess is that the '!' is pulling in some classes that are dependent on other assemblies.  You might try only generating a Shim for a specific class (and only the one class).  If that works, slowly add additional classes.

Comment: I have tried <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="nj4x.Strategy"/>
  </ShimGeneration>

Comment: But does not work.

Comment: @doobop The exclamationmark means "a class named exactly this". So Usama expects the nj4x namespace to contain a type called metatrader. He also expects a type in the global namespace called nj4x, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why but once I add fakes for NLog, fakes for required classes of nj4x are generated.